# How can I set the color for all aspects of an axis at once?

Tags: python, colors, matplotlib, axes

I'd like to set the color of major and minor ticks, tick labels, and the axis itself all to the same color, but the only way I've come up with to accomplish this is something like

```
fig, ax_a_mj = matplotlib.pyplot.subplots()

ax_a_mj.spines['bottom'].set_color('r')
ax_a_mj.tick_params(axis='x', colors='r')
ax_a_mj.tick_params(axis='x', colors='r', which='minor')
ax_a_mj.xaxis.label.set_color('r')
```

Is there no way to do this with a single statement?

How about the case where I want to do all axes, and I have four:

```
fig, ax_a_mj = matplotlib.pyplot.subplots()
ax_a_me = ax_a_mj.twinx()
ax_p_mj = ax_a_mj.twiny()

ax_a_mj.spines['bottom'].set_color('r')
ax_a_mj.spines['left'].set_color('r')
ax_a_mj.spines['right'].set_color('r')
ax_a_mj.spines['top'].set_color('r')
ax_a_mj.tick_params(axis='x', colors='r', which='both')
ax_a_mj.tick_params(axis='y', colors='r', which='both')
ax_p_mj.tick_params(axis='x', colors='r', which='both')
ax_a_me.tick_params(axis='y', colors='r', which='both')
ax_a_mj.xaxis.label.set_color('r')
ax_a_mj.yaxis.label.set_color('r')
ax_p_mj.xaxis.label.set_color('r')
ax_a_me.yaxis.label.set_color('r')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this a lot, just write your self a helper function

```
def colorize(ax_in, color_in):
    ax_in.spines['bottom'].set_color(color_in)
    ax_in.tick_params(axis='x', colors=color_in, which='both')
    ax_in.xaxis.label.set_color(color_in)
```

Note that `which` can be `'both'` which will set both the major and minor ticks [(doc)](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params).

If you are using this *a lot*, you can monkey patch it on to `Axes`

```
matplotlib.axes.Axes.my_colorize = colorize
```

and then

```
my_ax.my_colorize('r')
```

should work.

There is on going work to support style sheets by Tony Yu, the first bits of have already been merged into master (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2236).

Comment: Thanks. That looks like the answer. I've added to the question a bit: what about the case where I want to do this to all axes, and I have four. Is there any way to make that more compact than what I've got?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius don't modify your question to extend it after you have asked it, it is really annoying.  Just loop over a list of your axes calling colerize on each one.